# How can I store my extra wheels on the wall efficiently, without hanging them by the rim?

Tags: wheels, storage

I have 5 pair of extra wheels, which I would like to store on the wall efficiently.

I am a little skittish about storing them using the rim since some of them are carbon wheels and I don't want to risk scratches. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thats more spares than my LBS carries.....

Comment: You need a better LBS. :)

Comment: Clearly you need more bikes to store those wheels on...

Answer (score 12):

While I agree that there are no real risks to string your wheels by the rim, there are a number of DIY and commercial wall mounted racks for hanging wheels at the axle.

[Wheelzrack](http://wheelzrack.com) makes one good option, and even integrates a storage shelf for shoes and helmets. They support up to for sets of wheels, which may be a good option in your case.

[image: Wheelzrack example from home page]

Feedback sports used to offer a [Wheel Arm](http://feedbacksports.com/shop/Single-Wheel-Arm-Black-P105C28.aspx) system, which had a [bolt-to-wall mounting option](http://feedbacksports.com/shop/Wheel-Plate-Mount-P86C28.aspx) (note: the Wheel Arm is no longer listed on home page but they sell alternate models).  These are designd for shop displays, but will work in the home as well, assuming your significant other is tolerant. :-)

Hope that is helpful.

Comment: Thats a great idea, and it doesn't have to be an expensive rack made either - rescued forks might be all you need.   Mount ~6 in a row like your picture, but space them so that the rear wheel sits between adjacent forks.   Note the pic above alternates wheel depth on the "blades"

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/4206/5337), there's really no problem with hanging wheels or even an entire bike up by the rims. It's a good idea to pad the hook to avoid scratches, but this should be easy enough with some cheap foam or even tape.

Failing that, a narrow shelf with some blocks either side of each wheel to stop them rolling away would work and take up little space. I imagine you could even use a short loop of rope to hold a couple of wheels. To avoid touching the rims, you could loop this between the spokes and around the hub.

If the wall is rough, cover it with some cardboard or thin foam/rubber.

Answer (score 2):

If they are QR hubs you could remove the skewer and pass a length of cord through the axle, then knot it, so that the wheel could be hung by the cord.

Answer (score 2):

I have an old steel coffee-table leg screwed to the wall of my carport by the flanges at the top of the leg.

It holds about 6 random rims normally, and sticks out slightly upwards

To get more space and protect the nicer aluminium ones, I use a length of ribbon or soft rope like sash cord.  This goes around the rim and is tied in a loop with ~100 mm of slack.  Then the loop is hooked over the leg and left to hang.  Works well for me.

Advantage - soft cloth is in contact with the rim.

Downside - its still hanging by the rim.

---

Another option might be a frame somewhat more like a dishrack but for storing wheels?

[image]

Advantage - rims are protected

Downside - you'll have to make it.  And it will chew up floor space unless you make a wall-mounted one.

---

Final thought - how about one of these cheap wheel stands for each one?

[image]

Advantage - Just buy them, no making required

Downside - Floor space used up/clutter  Plus even cheap ones are $11-$12 US each which adds up.

Answer (score 1):

Put them in wheel bags and simply hang the bags up. Keeps wheels protected, clean and dust free. That's what I do.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, very simple DYI is to make a pair of clamps for each wheel, eg. metal plates (spacers?) , big enough to drill two holes: one to put axle through and one to pass cord through. Hang that cord on the hook or wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use the axle or support from below if you are not wanting to hang from the rim.

If you're going to slide them on a skewer then the other answers have plenty of suggestions.

If you're supporting from below, assuming you are leaning them against the wall then you need either a shelf or 2 poles perpendicular the the wall. You could hold poles up with shelf brackets and since your wheels will be light anyway you could get several deep.

You could anchor the end of the poles to the ceiling too if need be.

Answer (score 0):

HANG THEM BY THE RIM
Seriously get some hooks with a rubber coating on the outside from something like home depot or lowes or Amazon. then hang up the wheels. YOU WILL NOT SCRATCH THE RIMS. I hang my zipp 808 like this and they are fine. Heck, they are fine even when they have a bike attached. Look man I get beeing protective about the wheelset you just dropped hundreds of dollars on but you will waste more of your precious money or time if you don't go this route. Thats my 2 cents. Best of luck to you

Answer (score -1):

I've been making these for about 6 months now. Check them out at [image]http://www.foothillproducts.com/buy/offset-hook

Comment: Thank you for disclosing your affiliation. Unfortunately the OP wanted a way to hang them WITHOUT HANGING THEM FROM THE RIM so that would rule out your type of design. Thus the downvote, sorry.

Comment: p.s. Douglas - are you related to "Jeffrey" who posted a link to the same product several months ago in response to this question? His answer was deleted for promoting a single product.